# Criar Plugin de Busca Personalizada para Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Eu tenho que criar um **plugin para o wordpress**, no qual ele terá que fazer a pesquisa baseado no filtro selecionado. Exemplo:

> Quero encontrar lojas de roupas em uma determinada cidade.
>
> Após digitar no campo de busca a palavra 'roupas' e selecionar a
>   'cidade', será mostrado os resultados da busca.

Alguém poderia me ajudar me mostrando algum exemplo?

Comment: E como seria aquele código adaptado para a minha necessidade?

Comment: esse não é um bom formato de pergunta aqui pro SO. Na outra pergunta lincada tem o código de como buscar vários campos usando um seletor - que parece ser o seu caso. Você pode testar aquele e tentar adaptar, se não conseguir faça uma pergunta mais focada, com um exemplo de uso, que fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)